# RDP display configuration do not work for Mac

Tags: remote-desktop

I am using Microsoft Remote Desktop Client on Mac. I am always getting display on main display no matter what configuration I set. I want to get display on second monitor and here are my settings for it.

```
winposstr:s:0,1,1200,0,2880,1050
```

Same configuration working fine in Windows machine setup and get display on desired monitory but on Mac it don't work.

Here is my complete RDP file.

```
full address:s:MyPC.RDesktop
alternate full address:s:MyPC.RDesktop
gatewayhostname:s:58dbd129aexxxxxx.rsxx.rdesktop.com
gatewayusagemethod:i:1
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:1
gatewaycredentialssource:i:5
audiomode:i:0
devicestoredirect:s:1
drivestoredirect:s:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectcomports:i:1
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectsmartcards:i:1
audiocapturemode:i:0
bitmapcachesize:i:32000
camerastoredirect:s:1
domain:s:
gatewayaccesstoken:s:x
keyboardhook:i:2
networkautodetect:i:0
screen mode id:i:2 
winposstr:s:0,1,1200,0,2880,1050
```

Comment: The Mac itself should store the last window position used [as it does for all apps]. It doesn't need to be in the RDP file. btw, Mac RDP is absolutely nothing like Win RDP; it's developed by a totally different team. If you want to give feedback, use the beta available on https://install.appcenter.ms/orgs/rdmacios-k2vy/apps/microsoft-remote-desktop-for-mac/distribution_groups/all-users-of-microsoft-remote-desktop-for-mac They're good, you sometimes actually get feedback to your feedback, unlike most major corporate dev teams.

Comment: Where are you getting the `winposstr` from in the first place? It doesn't exist in Mac RDP, so you must have got it from Win.

Comment: @Tetsujin Trying Beta version. Here is Winposstr usage details https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/665.how-to-set-the-monitor-for-a-remote-desktop-session-in-a-multi-monitor-setup.aspx#Save_a_Separate_rdp_File_for_Each_Remote_Computer

Comment: That's for Windows, though. `winposstring`just  isn't in a Mac RDP document. I posted one to pastebin - https://pastebin.com/2bB53WUn - it's a lot different.

Comment: Ok, So how do we achieve it. Is there any alternative for getting display on extended monitor.

Comment: Just drag the window over. It will remember for next time. If you have "Displays have separate Spaces" *on* in System Prefs > Mission Control, then you'd have to set affinity to that Space - but that will affect the entire app, not just the one remote session.

Comment: Dragging app to extended display didn't work. I am getting display on main display on next session. How can I confirm that winposstr is not available for Mac.

Comment: Mac doesn't use the concept of 'extended display' like Windows does. Behaviour will depend on the pref I mentioned above.